# How does interfaces does set variable values outside the onResponse?

Tags: android, android-volley

So I've implemented a callback interface to store the returned onResponse data to a local variable in the MainActivity. Given that I have implemented it, I don't quite understand why interface is used in this case? Initially, I had a variable called `isValid`, which has been removed in the working code, to store the `onResponse` value, 1 or 0. But it cannot be accessed after being called in the main after `apiValid()`. Why is it so? Can someone explain? My code is below.

Callback Interface

```
public interface VolleyCallback{
        void onSuccess(String result);
}
```

The function apiValid:

```
 private void apiValid(final VolleyCallback callback,final String jwt){
        rq = MySingleton.getInstance(this.getApplicationContext()).getRequestQueue();
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, API_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                String result = response;
                callback.onSuccess(result);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                String option="verify";
                params.put("option",option);
                params.put("jwt",jwt);
                return params;
            }
        };
        MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(sr);
    }
```

Calling the function to execute the volley in MainActivity:

```
apiValid(new VolleyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String result) {
                    if(result.equals("1")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("Member",test_member);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }else{
                        Log.d("console","Invalid key");
                    }
                }
            })
```

Any explanation is appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: So you are basically not getting the result in main activity Right? If that is the case you may be not getting the response itself ... the api may be returning error response

Comment: Using this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739284/how-do-i-return-a-value-from-onresponse

Comment: @PraveenSP I am getting the result I want, I just don't quite understand how interface works in this case.